# Plotting two lines on the same figure using plotly dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly

My goal is to display a line graph and an average line on the same plot. This is for a Django project that displays a list of scores from a database. This database is pretty big (over 100k). The app shows an average line for each page (page only containing 20 results). I had this working using Scatter objects instead of Figure objects.

```
    plot_div = plot(
                    [Scatter(x=x_data, y=y_data) , Scatter(x=x_data, y=[statistics.fmean(y_data_float)]*20) ],
                    output_type='div', 
                    auto_open=False,
                    show_link=False,
                    config=dict(
                        displayModeBar=False,
                        )
                    
                    )
```

[image]
Also by the way I am using 
`from plotly.offline import plot`
`from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter`
Which is not recommended anymore in the newest version however for now this is the simplest way that I have found to get the plot output to being a div (instead of using `fig.show()` which would not work for my use case)

The reason why I am not happy with this working solution is because even though I have successfully turned the top mode bar off, the zoom function is still selected and I don't want users to be able to zoom. I have tried this out on a mobile application and the zoom makes the plot unusable. But I do still want the hover feature for users on a computer (which is why I don't want to make a static plot). I found a solution to fix this using some of the figure layout options and using a Figure instead of two Scatter objects for the `plot`

```
fig = dict({
    "data": [{"type": "scatter",
              "x": x_data,
              "y": y_data}] ,
    "layout": {"title": {"text": "Game Scores"},
                "xaxis_fixedrange": True,
                "yaxis_fixedrange": True}
    })

plot_div = plot(
                fig,
                output_type='div', 
                auto_open=False,
                show_link=False,
                config=dict(
                    displayModeBar=False,
                )
                    
            )
```

So now the zoom functionality has been disabled, but I am having trouble getting the average line on the same plot. I know I can't use an array of two Figure objects the same way I did with the Scatter Objects (I tried just to make sure :( ). Below is plotly's entire section from the documentation on creating figures with dictionaries.

```
fig = dict({
    "data": [{"type": "bar",
              "x": [1, 2, 3],
              "y": [1, 3, 2]}],
    "layout": {"title": {"text": "A Figure Specified By Python Dictionary"}}
})

# To display the figure defined by this dict, use the low-level plotly.io.show function
import plotly.io as pio

pio.show(fig)
```

I tried updating the fig code to have two lines on it.

```
fig = dict({
    "data": [[{"type": "scatter","x": x_data,"y": y_data}] , [{"type": "scatter","x": x_data,"y": [5]*20}]] ,
    "layout": {"title": {"text": "Game Scores"},
                "xaxis_fixedrange": True,
                "yaxis_fixedrange": True}
    })
```

and plotly didn't like that. Here is the error

```
Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property of
        Invalid elements include: [[{'type': 'scatter', 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 'y': ['212.124', '1.00', '14.2', '7.43', '21.21', '22.53', '4.24', '1.07', '1.01', '1.97', '1.41', '92.46', '1.09', '4.94', '1.0', '28.4', '16.05', '25.13', '1.2', '2.9']}], [{'type': 'scatter', 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 'y': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]}]]

    The 'data' property is a tuple of trace instances
    that may be specified as:
      - A list or tuple of trace instances
        (e.g. [Scatter(...), Bar(...)])
      - A single trace instance
        (e.g. Scatter(...), Bar(...), etc.)
      - A list or tuple of dicts of string/value properties where:
        - The 'type' property specifies the trace type
            One of: ['area', 'bar', 'barpolar', 'box',
                     'candlestick', 'carpet', 'choropleth',
                     'choroplethmapbox', 'cone', 'contour',
                     'contourcarpet', 'densitymapbox', 'funnel',
                     'funnelarea', 'heatmap', 'heatmapgl',
                     'histogram', 'histogram2d',
                     'histogram2dcontour', 'image', 'indicator',
                     'isosurface', 'mesh3d', 'ohlc', 'parcats',
                     'parcoords', 'pie', 'pointcloud', 'sankey',
                     'scatter', 'scatter3d', 'scattercarpet',
                     'scattergeo', 'scattergl', 'scattermapbox',
                     'scatterpolar', 'scatterpolargl',
                     'scatterternary', 'splom', 'streamtube',
                     'sunburst', 'surface', 'table', 'treemap',
                     'violin', 'volume', 'waterfall']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding what you want to accomplish, it looks like you can pass another trace instance such as `Scatter(...)` to the `data` property, and it will display both traces with the zoom functionality disabled.

```
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter

fig = dict({
    "data": [{"type": "scatter",
              "x": [1, 2, 3],
              "y": [1, 3, 2]},
              {"type": "scatter",
              "x": [1, 2, 3],
              "y": [5, 5, 5]}],
    "layout": {"title": {"text": "Game Scores"},
                "xaxis_fixedrange": True,
                "yaxis_fixedrange": True}
    })

# To display the figure defined by this dict, use the low-level plotly.io.show function
import plotly.io as pio

pio.show(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: Plotly is a bit finicky so it's understandable- glad to have helped :)